# Second order derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose a function $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$ of multivariable.
What's the condition to ensure that

$\frac{\partial^2 f}{dxdy}=\frac{\partial ^2 f}{dydx}$

Do we want it to be second order continuous or differentiable?

Further, what if we switch the domain to $\mathbb C^n$?

(Noticing the variable could be more than 2, i.e. $x,y,z...$, to which extent do we need it to be continuous? only $\frac{\partial ^2f}{d^2x}$ and $\frac{\partial ^2f}{d^2y}$, or all the $\frac{\partial ^2f}{d^2x},\frac{\partial ^2f}{d^2y},\frac{\partial ^2f}{d^2z}...$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called the *Mixed Derivative Theorem*: If $f(x,y)$ and its partial derivatives $f_x, f_y, f_{xy}, f_{yx}$ are defined throughout an open region containing the point in question $(a,b)$ and all these partial derivatives are continuous at $(a,b)$, then $f_{xy}(a,b) = f_{yx}(a,b)$ .

Reference:  Page 605 University Calculus  by Haas, Weir, and Thomas, 2009 edition.

Comment: Schwarz's theorem, (continuous) only stated for real $\mathbb R ^n$, what about the complex domain? $\mathbb C^n$